# How to change color/shape/size for a subset of data after plotting in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

There are lots of situations where I use ggplot to create a nice looking graph, but I would like to play around with the colors/shapes/sizes for data belonging to a certain group (e.g. to highlight it).

I understand how to set these properties differently for each group when I first create the plot. However, I would like to know if there is a simple command to change the properties **after the plot has been created** preferably without having to specify the properties for all other subsets).

As an example consider the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
x     = seq(0,1,0.2)
y     = seq(0,1,0.2)
types = c("a","a","a","b","b","c")
df = data.frame(x,y,types)

table_of_colors = c("a"="red","b"="blue","c"="green")
table_of_shapes = c("a"=15,"b"=15,"c"=16)

my_plot = ggplot(df) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y,color=types,shape=types),size=10) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = table_of_colors) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=table_of_shapes)
```

which produces the following plot:

[image: <code>my_plot</code>]

I'm wondering:

1. Is there a way to change the color of the green point (type=="c") without having to type out the colors for the other points?
2. Is there a way to change the shape of the blue/red points (type %in% c("a","b")) without having to type out the shapes for all the other points?
3. The size of all points is currently set to 10. Is there a way to change the size of *only* the green point to say 15, while keeping the size of all remaining points at 10?

I'm not sure if this is an existing feature, but hacks are welcome (so long as the changes will be reflected in the legend).

Comment: The only thing I can think of is plotting each type as a different layer, instead of plotting each type within the same layer. So, you could make one geom_point() call for type A, one geom_point() call for type B, so on and so forth, and that way get to granularly define things like point size and colour for each type.

Answer (score 4):

This seems kind of hacky to me, but the code below addresses items 1 and 2 in your list:

```
my_plot + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(table_of_colors[1:2],c="green")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(a=4,b=6, table_of_shapes[3]))
```

I thought maybe you could change the size with something like `scale_size_manual(values=c(10,10,15))`, but that doesn't work, perhaps because size was hard-coded, rather than set with an aesthetic to begin with.

It would probably be cleaner to just create new vectors of shapes, colors, etc., as needed, rather than to make individual *ad hoc* changes like those above.